# How to add conditional fields and sections to forms in Android app

Tags: android, forms, conditional-statements

I am building an android app that contains a form. The form has some fields that are to be included only if a user answered YES to a previous question. For example, the user is applying for a loan. So the user is asked to enter name and address. Then the user is asked `What is your employment status`? If the user answers `employed` or `self-employed` THEN a section about `employment` should be added to the form where user will enter data such as `job title`, `employer name`, `salary`, etc.

Here is an example:

```
first name: John
last name: Smith
marital status: (if user selects married, then a section about spouse should be added to the form)
employment status: (if user selects employed, then a section about employer should be added to the form)
date of birth:
email:
```

Note that the `conditional sections` are not added right under the question that triggered them. Rather, they are added at some later location on the form.

Comment: There is no question here. You need to ask for help on a specific problem

Comment: You also need to tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an onClick listener for the controls that need to add parts of the form. Define all the parts in your layout file, but wrap them in a container that has an id and `android:visibility="gone"`. When the user click on a view that controls one of those sections, have it set the visibility to visible. Just remember, if you are using a checkbox, you may need to manually call `checkbox.toggle()` in your onClick method.

Comment: You might want to use visibility="invisible".  The difference is that if invisible, the control is measured and laid out but is not visible, thus the containing layout will look the same, just with the control not visible.  If visibility is "gone", then the layout will not include the control at all so, for example, RelativeLayouts using this control as an anchor will break, LinearLayouts will size themselves as if the control was not even defined etc...

Comment: the problem with using invisible is that you will have blank spaces in your layout if they check no. if you cant guarantee that every section will be added in order (meaning you will NEVER select employed but not married), you should use GONE.

Comment: I didn't say "should use", I said "might want to use" as the OP did not make reference to how the containing layout(s) should behave.  It was not a comment on your answer, my intent was to supply a little more information ;)